how to create sub dataframes, appending rows if some column value is included in a list?
I have a dataframe like this
Data = pd.read_csv('info_com.csv')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(Data)

This DF has a column 'Code', that includes all product codes, and the DF pretty much includes all the information of said products. So, I have a list with the codes of interest, but in reality, I need two df, one with the rows of the "good codes" and one with the bad codes.
I tried doing some kind of sort, and a loop
   ComDF1 = df1['Codes']
   goodCodes = ['B0CD3589HR' ... 'B0CD726Q8T']


  for i in range(len(ComDF1)):
     if ComDF1[i] in goodCodes:
       df1.iloc[i].append(dfWP)
     else:
       df1.iloc[i].append(dfNWP)

  print(dfWP, dfNWP)

And expected two DF with all the info of every product, sorted by the existence or the absence of the column value in the list...

"I have a dataframe like this Data = pd.read_csv('info_com.csv') df1 = pd.DataFrame(Data)" -> this is not a [mre], we cannot guess what is in your info_com.csv file

I don't understand df1.iloc[i].append(dfWP) - maybe you mean dfWP.append( ComDF1[i] )

maybe dfWP = df1[ df1['Codes'].str.isin(goodCodes) ] ? and other with ~ to inverst selection dfNWP = df1[ ~df1['Codes'].str.isin(goodCodes) ]?

maybe better create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run.

@furas, yup, that was all it needed.
Thankyou.

I created some example data. Rather than looping over the rows, create a mask of the rows that you want and you can use that to grab those and then 'not those' with the tilde ~ operator.
import pandas as pd

example_data = [{'Codes': 'B0CD3589HR', 'other_data': '8675309'}, {'Codes': 'B0CD726Q8T', 'other_data': 'spam'},
                {'Codes': 'sdbadcodesdk', 'other_data': 'eggs'}, {'Codes': 'klbadzoot4d', 'other_data': 'a herring'},
                {'Codes': 'B0CD3589HR', 'other_data': 'a shrubbery'}, {'Codes': 'B0CD726Q8T', 'other_data': 'ni'}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(example_data)

goodCodes = ['B0CD3589HR', 'B0CD726Q8T']

good_code_rows_mask = df1['Codes'].isin(goodCodes)

good_codes_df = df1.loc[good_code_rows_mask]
not_good_codes_df = df1.loc[~good_code_rows_mask]


You don't need for-loop for this but .isin
df_wp = df[ df['Codes'].isin(good_codes) ]

and the same with ~ to invert selection
df_nwp = df[ ~df['Codes'].isin(good_codes) ]

Or using isin only once
mask = df['Codes'].isin(good_codes)

df_wp  = df[ mask]
df_nwp = df[~mask]


Minimal working code with example data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Codes': ['B0CD3589HR', 'wrong', 'B0CD726Q8T', 'blablabla' ],
    'Other': [12, 23, 34, 45],
})

good_codes = ['B0CD3589HR', 'B0CD726Q8T']   # PEP8: `lower_case_names` for variables

mask = df['Codes'].isin(good_codes)

df_wp  = df[ mask]
df_nwp = df[~mask]

print('--- mask ---')
print(mask)

print('--- df_wp ---')
print(df_wp)

print('--- df_nwp ---')
print(df_nwp)

Result:
--- mask ---
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: Codes, dtype: bool
--- df_wp ---
        Codes  Other
0  B0CD3589HR     12
2  B0CD726Q8T     34
--- df_nwp ---
       Codes  Other
1      wrong     23
3  blablabla     45

